# Python: How do I insert an Identity Matrix below a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, identity

I have a (3x5) matrix consisting of 3 arrays - np.ones(5), and 2 rows of 5 values. Something like:

```
 1 1 1 1 1 
 2 3 4 4 5 
 4 3 2 3 4
```

I Want to add an identity matrix of dimension (28) below this like:

```
 1 1 1 1 1 
 2 3 4 4 5 
 4 3 2 3 4 
 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 
 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I do this?

My code is this:

```
A = ([[np.ones(5), np.array(df['Beta'].values), np.array(-1*df.Beta.values), pd.DataFrame(np.identity(5))]])
```

This gives me 3 arrays and then an entire dataframe, so the entire matrix is not recognized as a matrix.

Comment: Looks like you want `vstack`, but I'm confused by "identity matrix of dimension (28)". Where is "28" coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate the arrays:

```
a=np.ones((3,3))
b=np.eye(3)
np.concatenate((a,b))
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stick `*np.identity(5)` into your list:

```
A = ([[ np.ones(5),
        np.array(df['Beta'].values),
        np.array(-1*df.Beta.values),
        pd.DataFrame(np.identity(5)),
        *np.identity(5)
     ]])
```